# Why Entity Framework Code First one to many Doesn't work properly

Tags: entity-framework, linq, code-first

I have two Tables Category and Product. I have entered some Data to the Category Table, then later I want to add some product based on the selected Category. When I try to add the Product it doesn't save the product data. This is the function that I have wrote for the update or appending row to Product table

```
public  void write(string Name, string Code, decimal Price,
                   string Image, Category Category,string Description)
    {
       using (var x = new MyDB())
      {
            Product pro = new Product
            {
                category = Category,
                CategoryID=Category.ID,
                PName = Name,
                Code = Code,
                Image = Image,
                Description = Description,
                Price = Price
            };     
            var row = x.categorys.Find(Category.ID);
            Category.product.Add(pro); 
            x.Entry(row).CurrentValues.SetValues(Category);
            x.SaveChanges();





        }
    }
```

also here is the tables that I have:

```
 public class Product
{
 public Product()
    {
        this.order = new HashSet<Order>();
    }
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Category category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> order { get; set; }


}
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.product = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique =true)]
    [Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> product { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my DbContext

```
public class MyDB : DbContext
{

    public MyDB()
        : base("name=MyDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDB, coffeeshopapp.Migrations.Configuration>("MyDB"));
    }


    public virtual DbSet<Category> categorys { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Product> products { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

Can somebody help me out with this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You have to modify your models as shown below.

```
public class Product
{

  public Product()
    {
        this.order = new HashSet<Order>();
    }

    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    public string PName { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public Int32 CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }


}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.product = new HashSet<Product>();
    }

    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique =true)]
    [Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

After that `Save` as shown below.

```
public  void write(string Name, string Code, decimal Price,
                   string Image, Category Category,string Description)
    {
       using (var x = new MyDB())
      {
            Product pro = new Product
            {
                Category = Category,
                PName = Name,
                Code = Code,
                Image = Image,
                Description = Description,
                Price = Price
            };     

           x.Products.Add(pro);
           x.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! but when I ran the code based on your modification I got this:   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Comment: can you show me your `saving` part after the changes ?

Comment: 'using (var x = new MyDB())
            {
                Product pro = new Product
                {
                    Category = Category,

                    PName = Name,
                    Code = Code,
                    Image = Image,
                    Description = Description,
                    Price = Price
                };
                x.products.Add(pro);
                x.SaveChanges();
            }'

Comment: it seems lowercase here `x.products` ? Is that typo ?

Comment: actually this  refers to public virtual DbSet<Product> products {get;set;} in MyDB: DBContext class

Comment: due to you're not following basic `naming conventions`, it seems you're having lot of issues? what is your collection now ? this on my post `public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }`

Comment: I Will Edit the question and add MyDB Class for better understanding, thanks for you help again.

Comment: One question,are you learning the EF with a sample project or is this a production task ?

Comment: is this ASP.net MVC 5 app or else ?

Comment: a WPF application

Comment: OK,if you follow this EF tutorial,I'm pretty much sure you can sort out above basic issue.After following the tutorial and modifying the code according to `code first conventions`,still having the issue please contact me.I'll help to you. Firstly you must modify your code base according to the conventions.That is must.Here is the tutorial :http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx